# Acumatica - How can we pass the Acumatica order item with "0" price

Tags: rest, api, acumatica

While creating an order to acumatica via postman. I am passing all the prices are 0 and the order takes the acumatica default prices which is wrong as we are passing the prices 0 but if we pass the prices  greater than 0 then it is passing the correct prices.

```
 URL : https://example.com/AcumaticaERP/entity/Default/17.200.001/SalesOrder/
Request type : PUT

"Details": [
{
"InventoryID": {
"value": "XTY-ONYX"
},
"OrderQty": {
"value": "0"
},
"UnitPrice": {
"value": "0"
},
"ExtendedPrice": {
"value": "0.00"
},
"DiscountAmount": {
"value": "0"
},
},

{
"InventoryID": {
"value": "78787878787"
},
"OrderQty": {
"value": "1.00"
},

"UnitPrice": {
"value": "0.00"
},
"ExtendedPrice": {
"value": "0.00"
},
"DiscountAmount": {
"value": "0"
}
}
```

Can anyone please let us know how can we update the 0 prices for the products in acumatia order without setting up the free product tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe adding ManualPrice (boolean) field to the Web Service Endpoint of the SalesOrder >> Details section can help: then pass this field in your request [image]